# Share a function between several views on ionic 2 angularjs 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

On several views on my app with ionic 2 and angularjs I'm using some ionic toast messages on every page.
These toast Messages are the same for every page.

Is it possible to define these messages in an injectable service or something rather than create the same function in all TS files ?

Comment: you should absolutely put the common functionality into an injectable service.  That's a very standard use case for services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like @Austin says, you should put your logic inside an `injectable service`:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ToastService {
  constructor(...) {
      // ...
  }

  showToast() {
      //....
  }
}
```

Then just include it in the `ionicBootstrap` of your `app.ts` file, in order to ensure that **the same instance of the service will be used in the entire application**.

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [ToastService], {});
```

And finally, you can use it in the `component` you want by doing:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastService} from './toastService';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/test.html'

})
export class TestPage {
  constructor(private toastService: ToastService) {
    // ...
  }

  showMessage() {  
      // Use the service to show the message
      this.toastService.showToast();
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a question : I tried to create the injectable file by using i 'ionic g Injectable ToastService' but the IONIC CLI return error saying Injectable is not a generator function.

Comment: `provider` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :) Please if you think this anwer is correct, mark it as the accepted one so other users know this solved the issue in the question.

Comment: You can find that information here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116231/discussion-between-runfast-webmaster-and-sebaferreras).